# Mixamo Animation and Unity: How to flip the coordinates of one of the bones in the animation?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a couple of basic animations I am getting from Mixamo and applying to a model in Unity, and am running into an issue.

In several of the Animations, key bones' movement is reversed.  For instance, in a turning cut to change direction, the left foot is backwards... and on a leaning run, the whole lower leg is reversed.  This seems like a simple fix...but I can't seem to do it through the unity rigger (and I guess now the Mixamo rigger is closed down).

Does anyone know how to correct this mistake?

**In fact, nearly every single mixamo animation has some critical flaw...**
However, "turn right" and "turn left" are completely working...so this feels like built in flaws in the file...Is that correct? Or could I be missing a step?

I have tried everything...changing the fbx to FBX for unity...I followed the instructions here https://community.mixamo.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203173978-Animation-not-working-feed-twisted-in-Unity5

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to download fbx for unity (maybe that isn't really even necessary), import the character model.  Set the character model to humanoid.

Next, when you import the animation (also fbx for unity download option) and you are configuring it for a humanoid character, choose "copy avatar" from the dropdown, where the default is to use the avatar provided with the animation.

Now, drag the avatar from the model object you are using in the scene onto the slot that "copy avatar" made available.

Finally, test it out by dragging onto an animation controller you've attached to the model.

Hopefully, everything works.  If it doesn't work, then you probably need to make sure that the character you imported is the exact character everything was rigged to on the mixamo site when you were choosing animations.